# How to check whether particular column completely match or not

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compare particular column with the other one.
For instance,when I compare A column with B by using some method,
it should return False.

```
    A   B
0   1   2
1   2   2
2   3   3
3   4   4
```

when I try

```
df.A==df.B
```

But this returns whether each elements match with the other.

How can I compare column with the other one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `equals`:

```
df['A'].equals(df['B'])
Out: False
```

This checks whether two Series are exactly the same - labels included.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `all`

```
(df.A == df.B).all()
```

---

```
df.A.eq(df.B)

0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

---

```
df.A.eq(df.B).all()

False
```